# Library not found for -lDJIWidget

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, dji-sdk

I am attempting to run the [sample developer dji application](https://developer.dji.com/document/2e5ae092-b0fa-4cbd-abe2-956f44253c12) for the iOS platform via `Xcode version 13.2.1`. Upon building the application for the ObjectiveC and Swift sample code, I get an error indicating "`Library not found for -lDJIWidget`".

mac os: `12.2.1`

I am a new macOS user, and this is my first time learning to build an iOS application for DJI. How can I resolve this error?

Trouble shooting steps taken

- ensure cocoapods is installed for both sample codes (objectiveC and swift code)
- use the `<Project>.xcworkspace` file for setting the bundle identifier and app key

Answer (score 1):

Connect your ios device to your computer and run the build off of it.

Comment: How can this possibly fix the issue? Connection the device won't make that library appear.

Comment: I looked through everything and noticed the library is there once you create and install the podfile. As to why it works, I'm not sure. I'm a new developer but I've noticed that when I build with my physical device(ios) it works. If I try any of the other simulators, it fails saying library not found.

Comment: OK, so in this case, it seems the library is only present when building for actual devices, however, that's an unusual thing to happen. Not unlikely, just unusual :)  The problem is on the provider side, as they didn't provide the framework binaries for simulator.

Comment: I had this problem after installing cocoapods because I'd accidentally loaded .xcodeproj instead of .xcworkspace